# OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Array should be CvMat or IplImage) in unknown function

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working now with opencv. And I have a problem with this code:

```
IplImage *original = cvLoadImage("C:\\4.jpg");

gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(original), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
```

On some images cvGetSize crashes with following: OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Array should be CvMat or IplImage) in unknown function, file ......\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 1238
While on others it works fine. Why could this happen?

Comment: Are you checking to make sure that `original` is not `null`? e.g., maybe some of the images fail to load entirely.

Comment: Exactly. The issue might be that the image fails to load and so OpenCV has no idea what the size should be.

Comment: **Never** assume the load worked correctly. I can practically guarantee that this is your issue.